expo prebuild sigue conectardno la app a expo
estoy haciendo un expo prebuild deseo no consumir mis 30 posibles compilaciones en expo.dev pero al hacer el prebuild me genera la carpeta android pero la misma me sigue pidiendo que use el expo start, y deseo es generar mis compilados desde android studio
he usado
nxp expo prebuild
genera la carpeta de android pero al compilar esta es como si siguiera necesitando estar conectado a expo o react native para poder trabajar

Bienvenido, recuerda nuevamente que debes aportar mayor información, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, tu pregunta anteriormente fue cerrada por esta misma situación. Te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos..

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

He especificado y aclarado bien el problema pero ya cierrenlo no entiendo realmente como esperan que lo ponga

Si tu haces npx expo prebuild no te consume los build de expo por que te genera las carpetas nativas nada mas, solo te consume cuando usas EAS de expo, puedes trabajar haciendo el prebuild y también con expo run:ios o expo run:android
